# Extract zip contents using ValueProvider as path in Apache Beam

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have a code that extracts the contents of .ZIP file in Google Cloud Storage. It works fine but I need to use this code with a filepath that will be provided at runtime("gs://some_bucket/filename.zip"). When I try it using runtime value I get an error like:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unable to serialize org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQueryQuerySource@187bc24
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.SerializableUtils.serializeToByteArray(SerializableUtils.java:53)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.SerializableUtils.ensureSerializable(SerializableUtils.java:83)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.Read$Bounded.<init>(Read.java:94)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.Read$Bounded.<init>(Read.java:89)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.Read.from(Read.java:48)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQueryIO$Read.expand(BigQueryIO.java:535)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQueryIO$Read.expand(BigQueryIO.java:292)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.applyInternal(Pipeline.java:482)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.applyTransform(Pipeline.java:422)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.values.PBegin.apply(PBegin.java:44)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.apply(Pipeline.java:164)
    at BeamTest2.StarterPipeline.main(StarterPipeline.java:180)
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.SerializableUtils.serializeToByteArray(SerializableUtils.java:49)
    ... 11 more
```

The code that I'm using is:

```
 //Unzip incoming file
      PCollection<TableRow> temp = p.apply(BigQueryIO.read().fromQuery(
      NestedValueProvider.of(
          options.getInputFile(),
          new SerializableFunction<String, String>() {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
            @Override
            public String apply(String filepath) {
                try{

                 List<GcsPath> gcsPaths = util.expand(GcsPath.fromUri(filepath));
                 LOG.info(gcsPaths+"FilesUnzipped");
                  List<String> paths = new ArrayList<String>();

                  for(GcsPath gcsp: gcsPaths){
                      paths.add(gcsp.toString());
                  }
                  p.apply(Create.of(paths))
                      .apply(ParDo.of(new UnzipFN(filepath)));

                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    LOG.info("Exception caught while extracting ZIP");
                }
                return "";
            }
          })).usingStandardSql().withoutValidation());
```

UnzipFN class:

```
public class UnzipFN extends DoFn<String,Long>{
    private long filesUnzipped=0;
    @ProcessElement
    public void processElement(ProcessContext c){
        String p = c.element();
        GcsUtilFactory factory = new GcsUtilFactory();
        GcsUtil u = factory.create(c.getPipelineOptions());
        byte[] buffer = new byte[100000000];
        try{
            SeekableByteChannel sek = u.open(GcsPath.fromUri(p));
            InputStream is = Channels.newInputStream(sek);
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
            ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(bis);
            ZipEntry ze = zis.getNextEntry();
            while(ze!=null){
                LOG.info("Unzipping File {}",ze.getName());
                WritableByteChannel wri = u.create(GcsPath.fromUri("gs://bucket_location/" + ze.getName()), getType(ze.getName()));
                OutputStream os = Channels.newOutputStream(wri);
                int len;
                while((len=zis.read(buffer))>0){
                    os.write(buffer,0,len);
                }
                os.close();
                filesUnzipped++;
                ze=zis.getNextEntry();


            }
            zis.closeEntry();
            zis.close();

        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    c.output(filesUnzipped);
    System.out.println(filesUnzipped+"FilesUnzipped");
    LOG.info("FilesUnzipped");
    }

    private String getType(String fName){
        if(fName.endsWith(".zip")){
            return "application/x-zip-compressed";
        }
        else {
            return "text/plain";
        }
    }
}
```

How to handle this scenario?

P.S. - The .zip extraction code has nothing to do with BigQueryIO.read(). I just used it as a hack to be able to read the runtime value. If you have any other suggestion for it please let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: The SerializableFunction in your NestedValueProvider always returns the empty string "" - is this intentional? And the resulting collection from applying UnzipFn is also ignored.

Comment: Also it seems like you're trying to add new graph steps to your pipeline inside the SerializableFunction of your NestedValueProvider. This is not possible: a pipeline is first constructed and then executed: you can not add new steps at runtime. I'm confused about what you're trying to do, so I'm not sure how to help you do it properly - please clarify what you're trying to do.

Comment: @jkff Yes that is intentional. So basically there is no resulting collection from UnzipFN. The job of UnzipFN is only to unzip and extract the contents of the .zip file whose path will be provided at runtime. So what I mean to ask is - How to unzip a file whose GCS location is provided at runtime? 
And if there is any other way other than what I'm doing please let me know.

Comment: @jkff I have also added the entire code that I will be using to unzip the file. You can have a look at it too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you have a `ValueProvider<String>` that contains a filepattern, and you are expanding the filepattern using `GcsUtil.expand()`, and you want to apply a function (`UnzipFn`) to each of the resulting filenames.

The current code will not work for several reasons:

- You're creating a `BigQueryIO.read().fromQuery()` where the argument of `fromQuery()` is a `ValueProvider` that always returns the empty string (your `NestedValueProvider`, after doing a bunch of stuff, always returns the empty string `""`). This will fail at runtime because the query can not be empty. Using `BigQueryIO` as a hack to try to get access to a `ValueProvider` is not a good idea - see below.
- You're adding steps to the pipeline inside the function for extracting the value from your `ValueProvider`. That function is called while the pipeline is running, from workers, to get the run-time value of the provider. It is not possible to add steps to the pipeline from its workers while the pipeline is running.
- You're capturing the `Pipeline` object into the `SerializableFunction` closure, and it fails to serialize, because `Pipeline` is not `Serializable` - because there is no legitimate use case for serializing the `Pipeline` Java object: it never needs to be shipped to workers or to a runner, it's only a temporary builder object used in your main program to construct something that you can later call `.run()` on. On the other hand, the `SerializableFunction` *will* be shipped to workers, so that they can evaluate the current value of the `ValueProvider`.

Think of a `ValueProvider` as a placeholder that has a value only when the pipeline runs, but not when it is constructed - e.g. you can call `provider.get()` from inside a `DoFn`. `NestedValueProvider` does not change this at all - it simply wraps another `ValueProvider` typically with some trivial conversion logic and is intended to be glue code for when you have a `ValueProvider<Something>` but need it as a `ValueProvider<SomethingSlightlyDifferent>`.

The crux of the matter is that you're trying to use a value available only at runtime (your `options.getInputFile()` `ValueProvider`) to do something construction-time - create the pipeline step `Create.of(paths)`. It is logically impossible to circumvent the unavailability of a `ValueProvider` at construction time: `ValueProvider` exists specifically to represent values that *haven't been supplied yet* at construction time, so they are left as placeholders in the pipeline description, and get supplied as arguments only when the pipeline is run. You need to come up with a pipeline structure where the input file is a placeholder, and the pipeline processes it in your desired way.

You can do it like this:

```
p.apply(Create.ofProvider(options.getInputFile(), StringUtf8Coder.of()))
 .apply(ParDo.of(new ExpandFn()))
 .apply(...fusion break...)
 .apply(ParDo.of(new UnzipFn()))
```

where `ExpandFn` will be a `DoFn` that takes a `String` and does your `GcsUtil.expand()` stuff, and for fusion break see e.g. implementation of `JdbcIO.java`.

In Beam 2.2 (you can use this at HEAD currently) you don't need an `ExpandFn` - there already exists a transform that can expand filepatterns and much more (e.g. it can incrementally expand the filepattern and keep watching for new files matching it, in a streaming pipeline). So you can write this more concisely:

```
p.apply(FileIO.match().filepattern(options.getInputFile()))
 .apply(...fusion break...)
 .apply(ParDo.of(new UnzipFn()));
```

Comment: Thanks @jkff it worked. And I didn't even have to perform fusion break.:)

Comment: Glad it worked, but note that without the fusion break this code is most likely going to use a single thread and have no parallelism.